# Fetching Data from super data type in looker

Tags: looker

I have a table which have a super datatype column. I want to fetch one column from data.
I was able to fetch it out in redshift
using

```
select metadata."oldEmailVerificationSent" from users_dev;
```

I want to do the same thing but in looker

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `metadata` is your SUPER type and you want to access a property that has a simple type, you should be able to access a SUPER property like any other dimension:

```
view: users_dev {
  dimension: oldEmailVerificationSent {
    sql: ${TABLE}.metadata."oldEmailVerificationSent" ;;
    type: boolean
  }
}
```